# Connection between 'Afuw and Tawbah: The Calf

Tags: tafseer, surat-al-baqarah, forgiveness

In Surah Baqarah, Allah says:

[image]

The key word here is **afaw**, from the same root as Allah's name Al-'Affuw, which means *to forgive something as if it never happened.*

A few verses later, Allah says:

[image]

The key here is the first part: "you wronged yourselves by worshipping the calf, so [here is the repentence] ..."

How is this connected to the mention of 'afaw in verse 52? Is it that the 'afaw came *after* they repented, or is there some other meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Due to [This tafseer](http://www.aviny.com/quran/tasnim/jeld-4/tasnim-07.aspx), The Afaw in this verse means that Allah gave those people a deadline until the Moses come back from the rendezvous instead of killing them or giving them desperate agony. As their sin was very very big (because they have seen how god rescued them and how kill pharaoh and after these miracles they started to worship a calf), Their Tawbah (repent) must have some conditions. Just Moses(sa) knows what is the condition for their Tawba became accepted. When Moses came down as it represents in the verse 54 ask them you have to kill yourselves until your Tawba became accepted.